# Wrapper class const correctness issue

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, wrapper, const-correctness

I'm trying to create a wrapper around JsonCpp's `Json::Value`.

I have a namespace `global` where I have functions that work on `Json::Value&` parameters. I want to create a more syntactically pleasing wrapper class for those functions.

This is a minimal example.

```
// Impl is a typedef for Json::Value, from JsonCpp

namespace global
{
    Impl& getChild(Impl& mImpl, const std::string& mName) { return mImpl[mName]; }
    const Impl& getChildConst(const Impl& mImpl, const std::string& mName) { return mImpl[mName]; }

    Impl::iterator beginNonConst(Impl& mRoot)           { return mRoot.begin(); }
    Impl::iterator endNonConst(Impl& mRoot)             { return mRoot.end(); }
    Impl::const_iterator beginConst(const Impl& mRoot)  { return mRoot.begin(); }
    Impl::const_iterator endConst(const Impl& mRoot)    { return mRoot.end(); }
}

class Wrapper
{
    private:
        Impl& impl;

    public:
        Wrapper(Impl& mImpl) : impl(mImpl) { }

        Wrapper operator[](const std::string& mName) { return global::getChild(impl, mName); }

        // Error here
        // no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const Impl {aka const Json::Value}' to 'Impl& {aka Json::Value&}'
        const Wrapper operator[](const std::string& mName) const { return global::getChildConst(impl, mName); }

        Impl::iterator begin()              { return global::beginNonConst(impl); }
        Impl::iterator end()                { return global::endNonConst(impl); }
        Impl::const_iterator begin() const  { return global::beginConst(impl); }
        Impl::const_iterator end() const    { return global::endConst(impl); }
};
```

This is what I want to be able to compile:

```
int main()
{
    Json::Value realValue;
    Wrapper w(realValue)
    for(const auto& i : w["numberArray"]) { cout << i << endl; }
    for(auto& i : w["numberArray"]) { i += 100; }

    // assert that changes have been made to realValue through the wrapper

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Wrapper` has a member of type `Impl&`.  Making the `Wrapper` object `const` only changes the top-level `const` of its members (which does nothing on a reference, references are already non-rebindable), and even that takes effect only after the constructor finishes.

You need a class with a member of type `const Impl&`, and `const Wrapper` does not.  The compiler is correctly preventing you from losing the `const` qualifier and passing a `const Impl&` to `Wrapper::Wrapper(Impl&)` which could mutate its argument.

Generally `const_iterator` is a separate class from `iterator`.  I see no reason why your `Wrapper` would be any different.

As a short-term solution, you can just use

```
const Wrapper operator[](const std::string& mName) const { return global::getChild(impl, mName); }
```

but this doesn't prevent anyone from copying the return value into a non-const `Wrapper` object and using it to mutate the `Impl`.

Comment: Heh, I just caught it after Zack's comment but you were writing your answer in meantime :)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't return type of both operator[] wrong? It should be Impl&/const Impl&, respectively?

Comment: Not necessarily. It looks like the OP is relying on implicit conversion to Wrapper.